# Using attempt in auth::group

Tags: php, laravel-7

I'm trying to use multi authentication for the users and admin but guard is not working. Error says unidentified medhod 'attempt'

```
if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']]))
```

Comment: do you have configured your auth.php?

Comment: Yes i have configured the authentication guard and providers in auth.php

Comment: `
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],`

Comment: maybe is caching the config, have you tried "php artisan cache:clear"?